# Error org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I have a problem with a project im designing. I am building a news app that uses a query to the Guardian website and im parsing the JSON response. 
I used tabs and fragments for this one. 
As i was trying to fix the initLoader my app stopped to be able to compile

```
package com.example.android.mynewsstand;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class EconomyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<News>> {

    /** Adapter for the list of earthquakes */
    private NewsListsAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final String GUARDIAN_QUERY = "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=sports&show-elements=image&api-key=test&show-fields=thumbnail&show-tags=contributor&order-by=newest";
    public static final String LOG_TAG = SportsFragment.class.getName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_list, container, false);

        getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();

        final ArrayList<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();


        mAdapter = new NewsListsAdapter(getActivity(), news);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return rootView;
       }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // Create a new loader for the given URL
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "test: onCreateLoader() called...");
        return new NewsLoader(getActivity().getApplication(), GUARDIAN_QUERY);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> news) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "test onLoadFinished() called...");
        mAdapter.clear();

        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        //mAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link News}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (news != null && !news.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(news);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<News>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "test: onLoaderReset() called...");
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

The error im getting now is the one in the header of my post

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
```

And this is my gradle

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.mynewsstand"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
}
```